# Badges that I earned on other sites show up in Chess.SE style in the trophy dialog

Tags: bug, design, badges

For some reason, when on Chess.SE and checking my little trophy thing, the badges show like they would for Chess, even for other sites such as Space Exploration:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit confusing indeed, but it's more or less [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). Performance-wise, it's not a good idea to load many stylesheet documents which would be necessary to give those icons the right shape (it's not just Chess and Space Exploration, *all* sites with custom designs could end up there). It was noted on Meta Stack Exchange: [Badge symbol in notification is of the site you're on, not where badge was earned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233517/295232) and the comments of staff member @AdamLear make clear it's not really a priority (though I do think the situation would improve by using the default circles [as suggested by @Raphael](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233517/badge-symbol-in-notification-is-of-the-site-youre-on-not-where-badge-was-earne#comment766546_233517), at least for the badges not from Chess.SE, and that wouldn't really hurt performance).